# R - Sum numeric values in selected rows and columns based on specific factor values

Tags: r, sum, data-cleaning

I have the following data.frame:

```
Engine      | MPG | Test_Distance
1. V6       | 17  |       751
2. V4       | 22  |       1850
3. V4-Hybrid| 26  |       210
4. V6-Hybrid| 24  |       85
5. Flat4    | 26  |       4560
6. V6-Hybrid| 28  |       124
7. Flat4    | 17  |       3455
8. V4       | 17  |       1642
```

Where Engine is a Factor vector, and MPG and Test_Distance are both numeric vectors.

Prior to making more complex stat calculations and plots, I want to simplify the data.frame by sorting:

- the Engine column by types (creating new values/rows and removing old ones),
- the MPG column with an average (mean) per Engine_type,
- the Test_Distance column by adding numeric values per type,
- add a new row with total averages.

Note: there are many other columns in this data.frame, but I only put three to simplify the approach.

Here's the resulting data.frame I'd like to have:

```
Engine_Type | MPG_avg | Test_Distance_total
1. Vx       |   18.7  |       4243
2. Vx_Hybrid|   26    |       419
3. Flatx    |   14.4  |       8015
4. TOTALS   |   19.7  |       12677
```

I tried using the `dplyr` and `plyr` packages and following functions: `aggregate`, `rowSums`, `colSums`, `data.table`. But to no avail. I thought of creating a temp data.frame, then re-integrate the new values in the original data.frame, but I'm hoping there's a quicker way to do it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I get the avg of Flatx as 21.5. ie. `mean(c(26, 17))#
[1] 21.5`

Answer (score 2):

We  replace the numbers in 'Engine' with 'x' within the `group_by`, `summarise` to get the `mean` and `sum` of the 'MPG' and 'Test_Distance' respectively, and bind the rows with the `mean` and `sum` of the summarised output

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%        
    group_by(Engine = sub("\\d+", "x", Engine)) %>%
    summarise(MPG = mean(MPG), Test_Distance_total = sum(Test_Distance))%>%
    bind_rows(tibble(Engine = 'TOTALS', 
                        MPG = mean(.$MPG), 
                        Test_Distance_total = sum(.$Test_Distance_total)))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Engine      MPG Test_Distance_total
#  <chr>     <dbl>               <int>
#1 Flatx      21.5                8015
#2 Vx         18.7                4243
#3 Vx-Hybrid  26.0                 419
#4 TOTALS     22.1               12677
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Engine = c("V6", "V4", "V4-Hybrid", "V6-Hybrid", 
"Flat4", "V6-Hybrid", "Flat4", "V4"), MPG = c(17L, 22L, 26L, 
24L, 26L, 28L, 17L, 17L), Test_Distance = c(751L, 1850L, 210L, 
85L, 4560L, 124L, 3455L, 1642L)), .Names = c("Engine", "MPG", 
"Test_Distance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.", "2.", 
"3.", "4.", "5.", "6.", "7.", "8."))
```